# How does decomposition occur?

Tags: database-design, 3nf

I have the following relation

```
R=(A,B,C,D,E)
```

given that A is the composite key
and this set of functional dependencies

```
F={A->B,B->C,C->D,D->E}.
```

Now,I know that this ia already in 2NF and I have to decompose it to 3NF.
My logic was like that:

```
R={A,B,C,D,E} where C is dependent on B,so
R1={A,B,D,E} with A->B,D->E
R2={B,C} PK is B
```

but there's also another dependency on R1,between D AND E,so

```
R3={A,B,D}
R4={D,E} PK is D
```

and my final results would be

```
 R2={B,C}
 R3={A,B,D}
 R4={D,E}
```

I know there's something wrong with my decomposition,but I don't know exactly where my mistake is.

Comment: Are you following some specific algorithm to bring the relation schema in 3NF or are you proceeding by trial-and-error? Also A is a candidate key, not a composite key. A composite key is a key formed by more than one attribute.

Comment: You probably mean, given that F is a cover, because otherwise the question can't be answered, and also that is what the algorithm/definitions require it to be. So find out what that is. Also quote those algorithms/definitions from your textbook & show all steps of your work following them. Otherwise for us to tell you where you are going wrong we have to. See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. What exactly was your assignment?